# meaning of "essential" in "Wall Street's essential function"

Tags: meaning

> Wall Street's **essential** function was to allocate capital: to decide who should get it and who should not.-*The Big Short: Inside the Doomsday Machine* by Michael Lewis-

I found two adjective meanings and I'm confused of which one is more close meaning in this sentence.

> essential:
> a)Absolutely necessary; extremely important
> b)Fundamental or central to the nature of something or someone
> (found on [Lexico Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/essential))

Comment: In the context of the sentence, it's b. Whether that is factual or not is another matter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! (even though I wonder as to why it is b :)

Comment: I think the usage is ambiguous, to the extent that the two senses truly are distinguishable. For example, I can easily find [*The essential function of a central bank is the maintenance of the stability of the monetary standard*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+essential+function+of+a+central+bank+is+the+maintenance+of+the+stability+of+the+monetary+standard%22) (unquestionably sense #a)...

Comment: ...and [The essential function of human intelligence is discernment between the Real and the illusory](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22The+essential+function+of+human+intelligence+is+discernment+between+the+Real+and+the+illusory%22) (clearly sense #b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment saying the meaning is
*b)Fundamental or central to the nature of something or someone*

The purpose of Wall Street is allocation of capital. That is its essence. Allocation of capital is necessary in capitalism, but it isn't necessarily true that only Wall Street can accomplish that.

Comment: convincible and understandable answer thanks!